# rsyslog not all the logs exist on central log server

Tags: rsyslog

I wanted all the logs from /var/log on clientserver to be copied to the logserver
Right now it only copies the kernel and sshd logs.

Changes I made to /etc/rsyslog.conf:
On the logserver I have:

```
$template SSS,    "/var/log/remotehosts/SSS/logs/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%/%HOSTNAME%-%$DAY%.log"

if $fromhost == 'clientserver' then ?SSS
& ~
```

On the clientserver I have:

```
*.*  @@logserver.domain:514
```

What I'm missing? why it did'nt it copy all the log files under /var/log?

Comment: Some files in `/var/log/` may be written to directly by a program, such as apache. These do not pass through syslog. You must configure rsyslog to read them separately, see module `imfile`.

Comment: In my case the *.* take only the sshd lines. I need other system logs to to move to the logserver. I dont understood, what may be the problem

Comment: The problem was in the logserver. All the files data arrived to a one central file